# Pandas: Adding columns to filter will mess with data structure

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the  `.dta` file behind this [zip file](http://ceprdata.org/wp-content/cps/data/cepr_org_2014.zip).

Here's the first row:

```
>>> df = pd.read_stata('cepr_org_2014.dta', convert_categoricals = False)
>>> df.iloc[0]
year                   2014
month                     1
minsamp                   8
hhid        000936071123039
hhid2                 91001
# [...]
>>> df.iloc[0]['wage4']
nan
```

I double check this using `stata`, it appears correct. So far, so good. Now I set up some columns that I want to keep and redo the exercise.

```
>>> columns = ['wbho', 'age', 'female', 'wage4', 'ind_nber']
columns2 = ['year', 'month', 'minsamp', 'hhid', 'hhid2', 'fnlwgt']
>>> df = pd.read_stata('cepr_org_2014.dta',
    convert_categoricals = False,
    columns=columns+columns2)
>>> df.iloc[0]
wbho                       1
age                       65
female                     0
wage4       1.7014118346e+38
ind_nber                 101
year                    2014
month                      1
minsamp                    8
hhid                     NaN
hhid2                    NaN
fnlwgt              560.1073
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

After adding a list of columns to keep, `pandas`

- doesn't understand the missing value anymore, `wage4` is large instead of `NaN`.
- Creates missing values for `hhid`, and `hhid2`.

Why?

*Foot note: first loading the dataset and then filtering using `df[columns+columns2]` works.*

Answer (score 1):

I traced this error to a bug in pandas. I've fixed the error in https://github.com/jbuyl/pandas/tree/fix-column-dtype-mixing and opened a pull request to merge in the fix, but feel free to checkout my fork/branch.

Here are the results running your example:

```
>>> columns = ['wbho', 'age', 'female', 'wage4', 'ind_nber']
>>> columns2 = ['year', 'month', 'minsamp', 'hhid', 'hhid2', 'fnlwgt']
>>> df = pd.read_stata('cepr_org_2014.dta',
...     convert_categoricals = False,
...     columns=columns+columns2)
>>> df.iloc[0]
wbho                      1
age                      65
female                    0
wage4                   nan
ind_nber                NaN
year                   2014
month                     1
minsamp                   8
hhid        000936071123039
hhid2                 91001
fnlwgt              560.107
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug, in the source of `pandas/io/stat.py`, in the `_do_select_columns()` method, the loop:

```
dtyplist = []
typlist = []
fmtlist = []
lbllist = []
matched = set()
for i, col in enumerate(data.columns):
    if col in column_set:
        matched.update([col])
        dtyplist.append(self.dtyplist[i])
        typlist.append(self.typlist[i])
        fmtlist.append(self.fmtlist[i])
        lbllist.append(self.lbllist[i])
```

messed up the order of `dtypes`, which no long matches the sequence as they appear in `column_set`.

Compare the `dtypes` of `df2` and `df3` in this example:

```
In [1]:

import zipfile
z = zipfile.ZipFile('/Users/q6600sl/Downloads/cepr_org_2014.zip')
df= pd.read_stata(z.open('cepr_org_2014.dta'), convert_categoricals = False)
In [2]:

columns = ['wbho', 'age', 'female', 'wage4', 'ind_nber']
columns2 = ['year', 'month', 'minsamp', 'hhid', 'hhid2', 'fnlwgt']
In [3]:

df2 = pd.read_stata(z.open('cepr_org_2014.dta'),
                    convert_categoricals = False,
                    columns=columns+columns2)
In [4]:

df2.dtypes
Out[4]:
wbho          int16
age            int8
female         int8
wage4        object
ind_nber     object
year        float32
month          int8
minsamp        int8
hhid        float64
hhid2       float64
fnlwgt      float32
dtype: object
In [5]:

df3 = df[columns+columns2]
In [6]:

df3.dtypes
Out[6]:
wbho           int8
age            int8
female         int8
wage4       float32
ind_nber    float64
year          int16
month          int8
minsamp        int8
hhid         object
hhid2        object
fnlwgt      float32
dtype: object
```

Change it to:

```
dtyplist = []
typlist = []
fmtlist = []
lbllist = []
#matched = set()
for i in np.hstack([np.argwhere(data.columns==col) for col in columns]).ravel():
#    if col in column_set:
#        matched.update([col])
    dtyplist.append(self.dtyplist[i])
    typlist.append(self.typlist[i])
    fmtlist.append(self.fmtlist[i])
    lbllist.append(self.lbllist[i])
```

fixed the problem.

(Don't know what `matched` is doing here. Appear to be never used later on.)